WebView sends X-requested-with header and getPackageName problem
I'm trying to send an empty X-requested-with header in Android WebView. As I have seen in other posts, this should work:
    override fun getPackageName(): String {
        try {
            // Override the value passed as X-Requested-With in WebView requests
            val stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().stackTrace
            for (element in stackTrace) {
                if ("org.chromium.base.BuildInfo".equals(element.className, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    if ("getAll".equals(element.methodName, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return WebViewUtil.SPOOF_PACKAGE_NAME
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        return super.getPackageName()
    }

But the problem is that my elements calling getPackageName are never "org.chromium.base.BuildInfo". I'm using standard WebView with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. Anyone figures out what the problem can be?
I'm using the log to check the elements returned. Never get the org.chromium.base.BuildInfo.

There is no requirement for a class named org.chromium.base.BuildInfo to be in any particular call stack. The developers can name their classes whatever they want, and those names can change at any point in time.

As you can see on https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/BuildInfo.java, webviews should use that class. But I can't see trace of it on my stacktrace.

"webviews should use that class" -- not necessarily. It could be used by Chrome and not WebView, for example. Even if the class is used by WebView, it might not be part of the call stack for your particular call. And, even if it is part of the call stack for your particular call, the code could be obfuscated, such that the class name is no longer what you are looking for. And the answers for all of those can change over time, so what is true today might not be true in six months.

Ok, understood. So I have to find another way to get rid of the X-Requested-With in webviews :-(

The first thing I would try is the loadUrl() variant that takes HTTP headers. Is this header special, such that this doesn't work?

I'm not using loadUrl() GET for my webview. I'm using postUrl() with no option to send custom headers. That's the problem. In addition, any other internal navigation request from the webview sends the x-requested-with header again.
